# Firestore rules request.auth always null

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

My firestore.rules always reject my request for missing or insufficient permissions, or so it says. I'm signing in with email and password prior to registering to my collection with .valueChanges() but it doesn't seem to work. I've used this configuration multiple times in the past without issues. Can you spot what I am missing here?

My firestore.rules look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here a a simple component reproducing the problem:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  showItems = false;
  items$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.items$ = firestore
      .collection('items')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          return of([]);
        })
      );
  }

  onAddItem() {
    return this.firestore
      .collection('items')
      .add({
        name: 'item',
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  onSignIn() {
    return this.auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword('timy@test.com', 'timothee')
      .then(() => {
        console.log('logged in!');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  onShowItems() {
    this.showItems = !this.showItems;
  }
}
```

With the corresponding template:

```
  <div>
    <button (click)="onSignIn()">Login</button>
    <button (click)="onShowItems()">Show Items</button>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showItems">
    <ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async as items; else loading">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #loading> Loading... </ng-template>
    <div>
      <button (click)="onAddItem()">Add Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
```

Upon changing my firestore.rules to `allow read, write: if true;` I successfully get access to my database.

Thank you so much for having a look at it... Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading Firebase back to version 8.6.1 solved the issue.

Watch https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4932 to track the issue on Firebase JS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

downgrade the firebase to  version 8.6.1

```
npm install firebase@8.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching a listener to the database before the user is signed in. To prevent this from happening [use an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private auth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {

    auth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        this.items$ = firestore
          .collection('items')
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
              console.error(err);
              return of([]);
            })
          );
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough to solve the problem, but still it may be part of it. Here is an issue opened on AngularFire that describes the symptoms I encountered: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2838

Comment: Assuming I am using an AngularFire route guard on the component I am accessing to my collection from, would I still need to subscribe to the collection AFTER checking the auth state?